# Find the first occurence of char c in char *s or return -1

Tags: c++

For a homework assignment, I need to implement a function which takes a `char *s` and a `char c` and return the index of c if found, and -1 otherwise.

Here's my first try:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    for (int i = 0; *s != '\0'; ++i, ++s) {
        if (*s == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Is that an okay implementation, or are there things to improve?

**EDIT** Sry, didn't mention that I only should use pointer-arithmetic/dereferencing, not something like s[i]. Besides, no use of the Standard Library is allowed.

Comment: char *off = strchr(s, c);  
if (off == NULL) return -1; else return (off - s);

Comment: s[i] is *(s+i). How is that not pointer arithmetic and dereferencing?

Comment: @Dead Of course it is. It's just that that kind of notation is not allowed in this homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is perfectly fine, as far as it goes. You should also write a simple test program that tests for the first char, last char, and a missing char.

Piling on to the 'other ways to do it' group, here is one with no `break`, a single `return`, and showing off pointer arithmetic. But, beware: if I were grading your homework, I would grade yours higher than mine. Yours is clear and maintainable, mine needlessly uses ?: and pointer subtraction.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int IndexOf(const char *s, const char c)
{
    const char * const p = s;
    while(*s && *s != c) s++;
    return (*s) ? s-p : -1;
}

#ifdef TEST
int main()
{
    printf("hello, h: %d\n", IndexOf("hello", 'h'));
    printf("hello, g: %d\n", IndexOf("hello", 'g'));
    printf("hello, o: %d\n", IndexOf("hello", 'o'));
    printf("hello, 0: %d\n", IndexOf("hello", 0));
}
#endif
```

The output of this program is:

```
hello, h: 0
hello, g: -1
hello, o: 4
hello, 0: -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fine, but you could increment only one variable:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Won't make any serious difference though, mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: What if 's' is NULL? there is no guarantee that the string is NULL terminated either...:)

Comment: @Chubsdad, both of those assumptions are the (kind of obvious) preconditions of this function, I pressume. :)

Comment: @Chubsdad Maybe I should introduce another param to also pass in a length?

Comment: exactly. that would be an inch closer. Or pass the array by reference.

Comment: @Chubsdad: passing by reference is not possible, it's C not C++

Comment: @Chubsdad, what if s is not NULL, but not a valid pointer?  What if the heap is corrupt?  If s is NULL, what should the function return? Seems to me that all these conditions are outside the scope of the problem.

Comment: @Helper Method: You assignment says "accepts char*" which implies a properly null-terminated string. Also `s[i]` is exactly the same as `*(s+i)`. If your assignment objects to `s[i]` just use `*(s+i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it without keeping track of the index:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    const char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == c) {
            return p - s;
        }
        ++p;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is not necessarily better than your solution.  Just demonstrating another way to use pointer arithmetic.

FWIW, I would define the function to return `size_t` rather than `int`.  Also, for real-world usage (not homework), you would probably want to consider what the proper behavior should be if `s` is a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me, at least given the signature. Just to add to the "many slightly different ways to do it" roadshow:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, const char c) {
    for (const char *p = s; *p != 0; ++p) {
        if (*p == c) return p - s;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Slight issue - `p-s` isn't guaranteed to work if the result is sufficiently big, and certainly goes wrong here if the correct result is bigger than `INT_MAX`. To fix this:

```
size_t IndexOf(const char *s, const char c) {
    for (size_t idx = 0; s[idx] != 0; ++idx) {
        if (s[idx] == c) return idx;
    }
    return SIZE_MAX;
}
```

As sharptooth says, if for some didactic reason you're not supposed to use the `s[i]` syntax, then `*(s+i)` is the same.

Note the slightly subtle point that because the input is required to be nul-terminated, the first occurrence of `c` cannot be at index `SIZE_MAX` unless `c` is 0 (and even then we're talking about a rather unusual C implementation). So it's OK to use `SIZE_MAX` as a magic value.

All the size issues can be avoided by returning a pointer to the found character (or null) instead of an index (or -1):

```
char *findchr(const char *s, const char c) {
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == c) return (char *)s;
        ++s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead you get an issue with const-safety, the same as the issue that the standard function `strchr` has with const-safety, and that can be fixed by providing const and non-const overloads.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo (`index` instead of `i`), but otherwise it looks fine. I doubt you'd be able to do much better than this (both in terms of efficiency and code clarity.)

Comment: In addition, loop index should not be 'int' in this case.

Comment: @Chubsdad#1 Which it is (`int i...`) or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chubsdad: Then the caller is a moron.

Comment: @aix: yes, better to unsigned for such looping that is bound to be non negative (logically)

Comment: @Chubsdad sorry, misread your original comment. For the record, I don't necessarily agree in this case.

Comment: @DeadMG: don't agree. It is a good opportunity to introduce at least 'assert'.

Comment: @Chubsdad: I also don't agree. The loop concept is easily simple enough for the index type to be irrelevant.

Comment: length of a string is logically a unsigned number. Then why use a type which hold negative values? Though insignficant in this case, it is a good thing to keep in mind while writing loops

Comment: @Helper: the reason not to use `int` is that the type is not defined to be big enough to hold any offset into any string. For example, on a 64bit implementation of C, `int` might be 32bits, `size_t` might be 64bits, and it may be perfectly possible to allocate a string which is >2GB.

Comment: @Steve + @Chubsdad +1 For the nice explanation, never thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you shoule return i;
not index.
I think it's just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant, as an old school C programmer may write it:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] && (s[i] != c)) ++i;
    return (s[i] == c)?i:-1;
}
```

Benefices : short, only one variable, only one return point, not break (considered harmful by some people).

For clarity I would probably go for the one below:

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It uses a break, but has only one return point, and is still short.

You can also notice I used plain 0 instead of `'\0'`, just to remind that char is a numeric type and that simple quotes are just a shorthand to convert letters to their values. Obviously comparing to 0 can also be replaced by `!` in C.

**EDIT:**

If only pointer arithmetic is allowed, this does not change much... really s[i] **is** pointer arithmetic... but you can rewrite it `*(s+i)` if you prefer (or even `i[s]` if you like obfuscation)

```
int IndexOf(const char *s, char c) {
    int result = -1;
    for (int i = 0; *(s+i) != 0; ++i) {
        if (*(s+i) == c) {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a version that works for most cases on x86 systems, one can use:

```
int IndexOf(char *s, char sr)
{
uint_t *x = (uint_t*)s;
uint_t msk[] = { 0xff, 0xff00, 0xff0000, 0xff000000 };
uint_t f[4] = { (uint_t)sr, (uint_t)sr << 8, (uint_t)sr << 16, (uint_t)sr << 24 };
uint_t c[4], m;

for (;;) {
    m = *x;
    c[0] = m & msk[0]; if (!c[0]) break; if (c[0] == f[0]) return (char*)x - s;
    c[1] = m & msk[1]; if (!c[1]) break; if (c[1] == f[1]) return (char*)x - s + 1;
    c[2] = m & msk[2]; if (!c[2]) break; if (c[2] == f[2]) return (char*)x - s + 2;
    c[3] = m & msk[3]; if (!c[3]) break; if (c[3] == f[3]) return (char*)x - s + 3;
    x++;
    }
return -1;
}
```

Limitations:

- It breaks if the string is shorter than four bytes *and* its address is closer to the end of a MMU page than four bytes.
- Also, the mask pattern is little endian, for big endian systems the order for the `msk[]` and `f[]` arrays has to be reversed.
- In addition, if the hardware can't do misaligned multi-byte accesses (x86 can) then if the string doesn't start at an address that's a multiple of four it'll also fail.

All of these are solveable with more elaborate versions, if you wish...

Why would you ever want to do weird things like that - what's the purpose ?
One does so for optimization. A char-by-char check is simple to code and understand but optimal performance, at least for strings above a certain length, tends to require operations on larger blocks of data. Your standard library code will contain some such "funny" things for that reason. If you compare larger blocks in a single operation (and with e.g. SSE2 instructions, one can extend this to 16 bytes at a time) more work gets done in the same time.